# Wordpress 'add page' hook

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to implement custom html in the red area as seen in the screenshot below, is there a hook for this? [image]

Comment: What did you find when you did your research?

Comment: @NathanDawson Sorry for my late response, but i found the hook 'post_submitbox_misc_actions' which adds an option to the side menu, but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a WordPress plugin called **Simply Show Hooks** which creates a visual indication of hooks that are being ran on the site which then led me to the hook `edit_form_after_editor`. That was the hook I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, i found another hook called 'edit_page_form' which works even better

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`add_meta_box`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).